# How to set uniform division using CSS in which column as well as row division is equal

Tags: php, html, css

In my code I want my content as 2 Blogs per row. The width is properly divided but height is creating problem. Some blogs have large Title and some has small so due to this uniform content is not printing. I some case it is taking more space and result affects next upcoming blog. Please look the image to be more clear about problem.

How to resolve it? I want to do something in which some imaginary box type division is provided for every blog so that it won't create indentation problem.

```
<div class="divide80"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php $i=1; include( 'admind/connect.php'); if(isset($_GET[ "page"])){ $page=$ _GET[ "page"]; } else{ $page=1; } $page1=($page-1)*6; ?>
    <?php $select="select * from blogs order by blog_id desc limit $page1,6" ; $run=mysql_query($select); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)) { $blog_id=$row[ 'blog_id']; $blog_title=$row[ 'blog_title']; $blog_date=$row[ 'blog_date']; $blog_author=$row[
    'blog_author']; $blog_image=$row[ 'blog_image']; $blog_content=substr($row[ 'blog_content'],0,170); ?>
    <?php if($i%2==1) { ?>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>">
        <div class="item-img-wrap">
          <center>
            <img src="imaged/<?php echo $blog_image; ?>" width="150px" height="200px" />
          </center>
          <div class="item-img-overlay">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!--work link-->
      <ul class="list-inline post-detail">
        <li>by
          <?php echo $blog_author; ?>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <?php echo $blog_date; ?>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h4><?php echo $blog_title; ?></h4>
      <p>
        <?php echo $blog_content; ?>
      </p>
      <p><a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" class="btn btn-theme-dark">
                                    Read more </a>
      </p>
      <hr>

    </div>

    <?php $i=$i+1; } else { ?>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>">
        <div class="item-img-wrap">
          <center>
            <img src="imaged/<?php echo $blog_image; ?>" width="150px" height="200px" />
          </center>
          <div class="item-img-overlay">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!--work link-->
      <ul class="list-inline post-detail">
        <li>by
          <?php echo $blog_author; ?>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <?php echo $blog_date; ?>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h4><?php echo $blog_title; ?></h4>
      <p>
        <?php echo $blog_content; ?>
      </p>
      <p><a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" class="btn btn-theme-dark">
                                            Read more </a>
      </p>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <?php } $i=$i+1; } ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Image 1:**

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2:**

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You need to add row each column, you are using "row" outside of the loop.

Comment: If possible can you provide the live link where you have uploaded the code.

Comment: I haven't uploaded it yet,I am running on localhost. @SayedRafeeq

Comment: I didn't get your first comment,will you please elaborate.Thanks ! @SayedRafeeq

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check this these code and let me know.

```html
<div class="divide80"></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="blog-post">
  <?php $i=1; include( 'admind/connect.php'); if(isset($_GET[ "page"])){ $page=$ _GET[ "page"]; } else{ $page=1; } $page1=($page-1)*6; ?>
  <?php $select="select * from blogs order by blog_id desc limit $page1,6" ; $run=mysql_query($select); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)) { $blog_id=$row[ 'blog_id']; $blog_title=$row[ 'blog_title']; $blog_date=$row[ 'blog_date']; $blog_author=$row[
 'blog_author']; $blog_image=$row[ 'blog_image']; $blog_content=substr($row[ 'blog_content'],0,170); ?>
  <?php if($i%2==1) { ?>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>">
    <div class="item-img-wrap">
      <center>
     <img src="imaged/<?php echo $blog_image; ?>" width="150px" height="200px" />
      </center>
      <div class="item-img-overlay">
     <span>
     </span>
      </div>
    </div>
     </a>
     <!--work link-->
     <ul class="list-inline post-detail">
    <li>by
      <?php echo $blog_author; ?>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-calendar">
      </i>
      <?php echo $blog_date; ?>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <h4>
    <?php echo $blog_title; ?>
     </h4>
     <p>
    <?php echo $blog_content; ?>
     </p>
     <p>
    <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" class="btn btn-theme-dark">
      Read more 
    </a>
     </p>
     <hr>
   </div>
   <?php $i=$i+1; } else { ?>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>">
    <div class="item-img-wrap">
      <center>
     <img src="imaged/<?php echo $blog_image; ?>" width="150px" height="200px" />
      </center>
      <div class="item-img-overlay">
     <span>
     </span>
      </div>
    </div>
     </a>
     <!--work link-->
     <ul class="list-inline post-detail">
    <li>by
      <?php echo $blog_author; ?>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-calendar">
      </i>
      <?php echo $blog_date; ?>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <h4>
    <?php echo $blog_title; ?>
     </h4>
     <p>
    <?php echo $blog_content; ?>
     </p>
     <p>
    <a href="pagesd.php?id=<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" class="btn btn-theme-dark">
      Read more 
    </a>
     </p>
     <hr>
   </div>
   <?php } $i=$i+1; } ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have checked this code but the problem still persist.